# byte to int type conversion network application

Tags: java, c, casting, network-programming, type-conversion

I'm sending from my android phone integer as byte with the following code(I put only the needed chunks):

```
private byte[] intToByteArray ( final int i ) throws IOException {      
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    dos.writeInt(i);
    dos.flush();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
//thread sender
        data = new byte[16];
        ...
        try {
            temp = intToByteArray((int) (roll*100));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        data[3] = temp[0];
        data[4] = temp[1];
        data[5] = temp[2];
        data[6] = temp[3];
        ...
        p = new DatagramPacket(data, 16);
        udpSocket.send(p);
```

The sending code works because I have tried it with a Java received, and the results are correct. The real receiver has to be implemented with an embedded device, Murata SN8200: I receive the packet, but I my integer results (for instance, roll) are not correct. The code that I'm using for converting from byte to int is the following:

```
void getSubArray(char* dest, char* source, int start, int end){
   uint8_t i, j = 0;
   for(i=start; i<end; i++){
       dest[j] = source[i];
       j++;
   }
}
int byteToInt(char* bytes)
{
  int ch1 = bytes[0];
  int ch2 = bytes[1];
  int ch3 = bytes[2];
  int ch4 = bytes[3];
  if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
      WPRINT_APP_INFO ( ("boh\r\n"));
  return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
}
...
//thread receiver
wiced_packet_get_data(packet, 0, (uint8_t**)&rx_data, &rx_data_length, &available_data_length);
traffic_type = rx_data[0];
        id = rx_data[1];
        takeOffPressed = rx_data[2];
        getSubArray(temp, rx_data, 3, 7);
        roll = byteToInt(temp);
        WPRINT_APP_INFO ( ("Rx: \" Packet Type: %c Id: %c  TakeOffPressed = %c \r\n  roll: %d \r\n ", (unsigned char )traffic_type, (unsigned char )id, (unsigned char)takeOffPressed, roll);
```

Reading other discussions I have already tried to do: roll = (int*)(temp); as suggested in another post, but it doesn't work for me (aliasing compiler error). Any idea to solve the problem? thanks

Comment: your phone send integer which is 4 bytes I suppose it does it in big endian?when receiving it you have to convert it in your local endianess...in the place of void getSubArray why not use memcpy ?

Comment: Remember to convert to host order from network order. Otherwise your bytes *may* be the wrong way around.

Have a look at htonl and ntohl.

Comment: Yes please print the value in `hex` and check that the bytes are not in reverse order, if the are you just need to convert them from their endiannes to the correct one.

Comment: I don't see how the Java code you presented can "work", since `p = new DatagramPacket(data, 16); udpSocket.send(p[0]);` should not even *compile*.

Comment: @JesperBangsholt, yes and no.  Network byte order does not happen automagically -- the byte order of the message is chosen by the sender. In this case it *happens* to be network byte order, but that's a function of the behavior of `DataOutputStream,writeInt()`, whose documentation does not cast it in those terms.

Comment: roll = (int*)temp; ??? but in your code you did roll=byteToInt(temp); which return an int...it is not good. roll=(int)temp; is much suitable.

Comment: Anyway, it's not a byte-order problem.  The `byteToInt()` function presented implements the correct byte order, but it has other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some possible signedness confusion.  Consider your `byteToInt()` function:

```
int byteToInt(char* bytes)
{
  int ch1 = bytes[0];
  int ch2 = bytes[1];
  int ch3 = bytes[2];
  int ch4 = bytes[3];
  if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
      WPRINT_APP_INFO ( ("boh\r\n"));
  return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
}
```

Suppose the 4-byte value that was sent was `511` (decimal).  The bytes sent are then `0x00 0x00 0x01 0xff`.  Now suppose that the receiving system features signed, two's complement `char`s, which is not uncommon.  In that case, on the receiver those chars will be interpreted as values `0 0 1 -1` (decimal).  There are now two problems with this:

1. The behavior of applying a shift operator to a negative left operand (i.e. the value of `ch4` in my example) is undefined.
2. A reasonably likely actual behavior for `-1 << 0` would be to yield `-1` (a zero-bit shift evaluating to the value of its left operand).  In that case, the overall computed value would be `256 + -1 = 255`.

Of course, that's just an example, but only one in sixteen 32-bit `int`s have the high bit of every byte clear.

Both issues could be addressed by performing the computation with the appropriate unsigned quantities.  That could be done like this:

```
int byteToInt(char* bytes)
{
  uint8_t ch1 = bytes[0];
  uint8_t ch2 = bytes[1];
  uint8_t ch3 = bytes[2];
  uint8_t ch4 = bytes[3];
  return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
}
```

Note, too, that it is wasteful to extract a subarray to pass to `byteToInt()`.  It would be better to just use a bit of pointer arithmetic:

```
roll = byteToInt(rx_data + 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

uint32_t byteToInt(char* bytes)
{
 uint8_t b[4];
 memcpy(b, bytes, 4);
 if ((b[0] | b[1] | b[2] | b[3]) < 0)WPRINT_APP_INFO ( ("boh\r\n"));
 return ntohl(*((uint32_t *)b));
}
 ...
 //thread receiver
wiced_packet_get_data(packet, 0, (uint8_t**)&rx_data, &rx_data_length, &available_data_length);
traffic_type = rx_data[0];
id = rx_data[1];
takeOffPressed = rx_data[2];
memcpy(temp, rx_data+3, 4);
roll = byteToInt(temp);
WPRINT_APP_INFO ( ("Rx: \" Packet Type: %c Id: %c  TakeOffPressed = %c \r\n  roll: %d \r\n ", (unsigned char )traffic_type, (unsigned char )id, (unsigned char)takeOffPressed, roll);
```

no need of

```
void getSubArray(char* dest, char* source, int start, int end)
```

you can replace it by a

```
memcpy(void* dest, void* src, size_t t);//from string.h
```

alse I have modified your byteToInt function to a thing more interessting